# How to save variables value permanently in QT?

Tags: android, qt

I need to save variable data in QT (QML environment), even  if the launched device is rebooted or shutdown.
I need something like Micro controllers EEPROM memory in my android devices through QT IDE any idea how to implement this?

Comment: What did you try , JSON ... `QSettings()` ...?

Comment: @MohammadAKanan no, I'm new in QT and still looking for a solution, Is JSON  my answer?

Comment: You can store your app state and settings in Qt Android .. with `QSettings()` , for example this thread [Qt session management on Android and IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48168909/qt-session-management-on-android-and-ios)

Comment: @MohammadAKanan thank for the answer, Is there any way to do this in QML section not in C++ ?

Comment: You can expose a C++ "Writer" object to the QML engine and from there access any `QSettings` or whatever is suited for your application (EEPROM, ..) . This example might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882518/reading-and-writing-files-in-qml-qt

Comment: Yes , you can  use Settings in QML directly , [Settings QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html)